# Outdoor IP Camera with built in FTP (SFTP, web) server

Tags: ip-camera, waterproof

I am looking for an outdoor IP camera with night vision and good resolution, ability to cover distances about 100 m with good detail (registration plate, face etc.). There are some good recommendations [in this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/59/weatherproof-ip-camera-for-long-distances).

It is quite common for theese cameras to have an SD card inserted and recordings can be saved there. Is there a chance there is some IP camera with built-in FTP, SFTP server, or with HTTPS download of recorded video files periodically (nightly)? Like it is possible from an IPCorder device. Or to setup FTP send to some given schedule, like every day at 22:00.

Seems like [VIVOTEK 8372](http://www.vivotek.com/fd8372/#overview) can be configured to send FTP data only when defined event fires, which could be OK, but it is not well documented how it actually works. From [this link](https://www.cameraftp.com/CameraFTP/Support/SupportedCameras.aspx) it seems that it is rather used for sending pictures from the camera to be shown on a web page which is quite useless for this purpose.

---

Looking around my last hot candidate are Panasonic cameras WV-SFV6 series - in their [manual](http://ssbu-t.psn-web.net/Products/IP_camera/WV-SFV631L_611L/Manual/PGQP1582WAC1_WV-SPN631_OI_en.pdf) there is on the page 160 an option `Allow FTP access to camera`. This seems to be promising, even there is a data structure on the last page that looks very well, any experience with this or anything similar?
The problem is that theese cameras are relatively expensive and perhaps installing less expensive camera tohether with NVR would be less costly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the ONVIF standard is the future way of getting recorded videos from devices like IP cameras.

By typing **Profile G** into [this web page](http://www.onvif.org/ConformantProducts/ProfileProducts.aspx) you can get a list of compatible device, mostly IP cameras, and very few client software apps (only 2).

Recordings are being accessed via URL like this

http://10.8.3.173/onvif/Recording

But we must still wait for a decent SDK, that would enable to create Onvif G profile client in languages like C#, so it is hardly usable yet.